# Weird exception with authentication in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, redirect, authentication

I want to redirect http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/admins/deshboard after successful login and http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/admins/login if login failed. My code inside adminsController:

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {

    var $layout = 'admin';

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }

    function isAuthorized($user) {
        if (isset($user['Admin'])) {
            if ($user['Admin']['status'] == 'active') {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    function login() {
        $this->loadModel('Admin');
        $this->layout = "admin-login";
        // if already logged in check this step
        if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
            return $this->redirect(
                            array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'deshboard'));
        }
        // after submit login form check this step
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $password = Security::hash($this->request->data['Admin']['password'], NULL, true);

            $admin = $this->Admin->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('email' => $this->request->data['Admin']['email'], 'password' => $password)
            ));
            if ($this->isAuthorized($admin)) {

                $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Admin']);
                return $this->redirect('/admins/deshboard');
            } else {

                $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username/password combination OR you are blocked, try again');
                return $this->redirect('/admins/login');
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        // $user = $this->Auth->user();
        // $this->Session->destroy();

        $this->Session->setFlash('you have successfully logged out');
        $this->Auth->logout();
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
    }

    function deshboard() {

    }
}
```

Code Inside AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                        'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'Agent'
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'admins',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'deshboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => "You can't acces that page",
            'authorize' => 'Controller'
        )
    );
     public function beforeFilter() {
        //parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
    }
}
```

When I try to login it redirects to http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/admins/login if login failed. its fine. but when I provide valid email and password and login successful it redirects to `http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/amrajegeachi14/admins/deshboard`. its wrong it should be `http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/admins/deshboard`

I am surprised when I changed the isAuthorized() function as follows:

```
 function isAuthorized($user) {
            if (isset($user['Admin'])) {
                if ($user['Admin']['status'] == 'active') {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

it redirects http://localhost/amrajegeachi14/admins/deshboard with successful login. But in this case login will be okay with incorrect username and password.

This problem kills my sleep, makes me crazy and I am so much disappointed. I searched google for two days but no appropriate solution. Please help me.

Comment: I don't know what cause your problem, but you should not call  `isAuthorized` in your `login` method. Actually, you should never call `isAuthorized` manually. The `login` action is used to authenticate an user, not to check its authorisation.

Comment: Exactly. I'd suggest that you start by reading [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) to understand the difference between authorization and authentication. Also please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using, and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.6.9.
if remove isAuthorized() it shows:
'$controller does not implement an isAuthorized() method.' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your user is never logged in because you did not follow the CakePHP way of authenticating an user. Here is your code with comments:

```
// This should not be here... This should either be in a authentication 
// component, or maybe not present at all if you use default authentication.
$password = Security::hash($this->request->data['Admin']['password'], NULL, true);
$admin = $this->Admin->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'email' => $this->request->data['Admin']['email'], 
        'password' => $password
    )
));
// This should not be called manually.
if ($this->isAuthorized($admin)) {
    // Your problem is probably here, since you never check the return
    // value of the login function.
    $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Admin']);
    // You should use $this->Auth->redirectUrl()
    return $this->redirect('/admins/deshboard');
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username/password combination OR you are blocked, try again');
    return $this->redirect('/admins/login');
}
```

I am pretty sure that the `$this->Auth->login ()` call always return `false`. The login method will try to authenticate an user, using the authentication component you specified (or the default one).

Your passwords are probably hashed in your DB, but you did not tell the component how to hash them, so it cannot authenticate your users...

Comment: Thanks a lot Holt. One more question. I used the following hashing code while insert data in db.    
function hashPassword() {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'], NULL, true
        );
    }

    function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->hashPassword();
        return true;
    }
So how could I set this hashing method to auth component. 
N.B:Sorry if I am asking like nonsense. I am new in cakephp.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan And because you are new, you should start with reading the docs to get a grasp on the basics, it's all described there, including examples.

Comment: Corrected as you suggested but now I got the following error:
$controller does not implement an isAuthorized() method